# using variable in jquery selector

Tags: jquery

I am having trouble getting the code below to work I am not getting any errors. What I need is when `#equipmentList1` Changes it displays a dropdown list corresponding to the selection. Then depending on the selecting of the later dropdown it should just write the value of the dropdown selected to the `equipmentList2` DIV. `selectedVisibleValue1` contains the ID of the field that appears after the first dropdown is chosen I have tried passing it into the second function to write it using `innerHTML` but it acts like it is not receiving the variable since nothing happens. Maybe I have an error elsewhere in my code. I am new to jQuery so if someone could take a look and let me know what is wrong that would be awesome.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#equipmentList1').bind('change', function () {
    var elements = $('div.equipmentList2').children().hide(); // hide all the elements
    var value = $(this).val();    

    if (value.length) { // if somethings' selected
      elements.filter('.' + value).show(); // show the ones we want
      var selectedVisibleValue1 = $(".equipmentList2 select:visible").attr("id");
    }
  }).trigger('change');
});   

$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#" + selectedVisibleValue1).bind('change', function () {
    var value = $(this).val();  

    if (value.length) {
      var equipment = document.getElementById("equipmentList1").value;
      document.getElementById('equipmentList2').innerHTML = selectedVisibleValue1;
    }
  }).trigger('change');
});
```

Comment: show us some html. Code you have won't work. `selectedVisibleValue1` isn't known until a change occurs in other select. Use class as selector to bind change to second select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need two `$(document).ready(...)` functions, only one, put all the code in one of them.
I'm not sure that's the cause of the issue but there is a good chance.